# Comparar fechas en MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Dispongo de un `datetime` que usualmente es igual a `Now` de VB, por lo tanto de formato `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:fff`.

Lo que quiero realizar y no consigo es comparar dicha fecha con una columna de tipo `datetime` y devolver los resultados que comparten `YYYY-MM-DD HH`. Es decir, que me devuelva todas las filas del mismo día y hora, independientemente de minutos, segundos o milisegundos.

He valorado pasar las fechas a string y cortarlas y así realizar la comparación, pero me parece un método un poco *sucio*.

He revisado la documentación de [cast](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-previousversions) pero no tengo nada claro que me pueda servir.

Yo me había imaginado algo así:

```
SELECT *
FROM X
WHERE fnFormato(FechaHora,'YYYY-MM-DD HH') = fnFormato(@Now,'YYYY-MM-DD HH')
```

Comment: Te he redactado una respuesta con una posible solución a tu problema. No puedo probarlo en un SQL Server 2008 porque salió de soporte hace casi 5 años, el pasado 8 de julio de 2014, y no me queda ninguna instancia de esa versión para probar (y en la documentación de Microsoft ya no hacen referencia a ella).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con dar formato a la fecha de esta manera:

```
SELECT *
FROM X
WHERE
  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), FechaHora, 120), 13) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), @Now, 120), 13)
```

He dejado una version en línea [(aquí)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/75533/11) para que puedas probarlo.

Si el campo de `FechaHora` es un índice, y tienes un elevado número de registros, podrás optimizar la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
DECLARE @Inicio AS DATETIME, @Final AS DATETIME, @Raiz AS VARCHAR(13)
SET @Raiz = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), @Now, 120), 13)
SET @Inicio = CAST(CONCAT(@Raiz, ':00:00') as DATETIME)
SET @Final = CAST(CONCAT(@Raiz, ':59:59') as DATETIME)
SELECT
  *, @Inicio, @Final,
  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), FechaHora, 120), 13) now
FROM
  X
WHERE
  FechaHora BETWEEN @Inicio AND @Final
```

Calculo el rango de tiempo comprendido entre `YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00` y `YYYY-MM-DD HH:59:59` en variables de tipo `datetime` para que la búsqueda se haga lo más eficientemente posible.

También se puede hacer todo en una única consulta:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  X
WHERE
  FechaHora BETWEEN
    CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), @Now, 120), 13), ':00:00') as DATETIME)
    AND CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), @Now, 120), 13), ':59:59') as DATETIME)
```

Comment: Me temo que ya lo había probado. Esa función no está disponible en SQL SERVER 2008.

Comment: ¿Podrías probar con `LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), FechaHora, 120), 13)`?

Comment: ¿Cómo? No acabo de entender la sentencia. Ah vale, que has editado la respuesta. Dame un momento.

Comment: No es óptimo porque hago dos llamadas a funciones para obtener el resultado (primero un `CONVERT()` y luego un `LEFT()`), pero he comprobado que funciona en SQL 2017 y teóricamente debería ser totalmente compatible con SQL 2008.

Comment: Tiene buena pinta, voy a probarla en el entorno real. Me podrías explicar qué hacen el 120 y el 13?

Comment: El `120` es el parámetro de `CONVERT()` que indica el formato de fecha (ODBC canónico, `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` en formato de 24 horas). Aquí tienes el listado: [https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles). El `13` es el parámetro de `LEFT()` que indica el número de caracteres con los que me quedo contando desde la izquierda (hasta cubrir el `MM` son 13 caracteres).

Comment: Pues ya está, muchas gracias :)

Comment: ¡De nada! Un placer ser de ayuda. En cuanto llegue a casa incorporo la explicación y los enlaces a la documentación oficial dentro de la respuesta.

Comment: Viendo un comentario sobre que no se están usando índices (si tu campo lo es) se puede optimizar la consulta para que los use de la manera más eficiente posible. En unos minutos edito la respuesta.

Comment: Le echaré un vistazo pero de momento hablamos de 5k líneas por lo que la consulta inicial funciona bien.

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta que si aplicas una función a una columna en el WHERE, es muy probable que no puedas utilizar índices y tus consultas se vuelvan lentas. Para evitar eso, lo que se debe hacer es manejar rangos.

```
SELECT *
FROM X
WHERE FechaHora >= DATEADD( HH, DATEDIFF( HH, '2020', @Now), '2020')
AND FechaHora < DATEADD( HH, DATEDIFF( HH, '2020', @Now) + 1, '2020');
```

Para enteder los rangos, te explico un poco como funciona la combinación de las funciones de fecha.

- Primero tomo una fecha fija. En este caso es '2020' que se interpreta como '2020-01-01'. Esto nos da bastante espacio para jugar con fechas.
- Después uso DATEDIFF para tomar la cantidad de horas desde esa fecha hasta la que queremos afectar `@Now`.
- Finalmente agrego (en este caso se resta por ser un valor negativo) las horas a la fecha fija especificada anteriormente.

Y así tenemos nuestras funciones para truncar fechas en SQL Server que se pueden usar para días, semanas, meses, semestres y trimestres.

Por último, dejo una prueba de rendimiento porque nunca debes de creer en alguien que te dice que algo es mejor si no puede probarlo.

```
--Creamos una tabla de prueba
CREATE TABLE X(FechaHora datetime)
--Le creamos un índice
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_X_FechaHora ON X(FechaHora);

-- Insertamos un millón de filas aleatorias
INSERT INTO X
SELECT TOP(1000000)
    DATEADD( ss, CHECKSUM(NEWID())%1000000, GETDATE())
FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b

--Inicializamos nuestra variable
DECLARE @Now datetime = GETDATE();
--Indicamos que nos muestren las mediciones de tiempo y lectura
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
--Incluimos ambas opciones para ver cual funciona mejor
SELECT *
FROM X
WHERE LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), FechaHora, 120), 13) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), @Now, 120), 13);
--Así separamos nuestras mediciones
PRINT  '-------------------------------------' 
SELECT *
FROM X
WHERE FechaHora >= DATEADD( HH, DATEDIFF( HH, '2020', @Now), '2020') --Mayor o igual que el límite inferior
AND FechaHora < DATEADD( HH, DATEDIFF( HH, '2020', @Now) + 1, '2020'); --Menor que el límite superior

--Dejamos de tomar mediciones
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;

GO
--Limpiamos nuestra prueba
DROP TABLE X;
```

Comment: En cuanto al enfoque de rendimiento, debo decir que me gusta el enfoque que le das a la respuesta, pero también que muchas veces, tener código _óptimo_ implica un mayor costo de mantenimiento. A veces se sabe de antemano que el volumen de datos y/o usuarios va a ser bajo y en esos casos yo suelo sacrificar sin ninguna pena desempeño por facilidad de mantenimiento y usar algoritmos o consultas más simples. De hecho, suelo recomendar no hacer muchas optimizaciones prematuras. Digo eso, siendo personalmente fanático del buen desempeño. Un saludo.

Comment: Por otro lado, para hacer justicia, creo que tu ejemplo debiera utilizar otro campo con el `clustered index` y la fecha en un índice secundario. Las probabilidades de que, en la vida real, sea una fecha la que ocupa esa posición son cercanas a cero, y ambos sabemos que se va a beneficiar por mucho la consulta en el acceso físico a los datos.

Comment: Creo que tenemos experiencias distintas. Una columna tipo fecha es un buen candidato para ser parte de un `clustered index`. Todo depende del tipo de tabla y el uso que se le dé. En ocasiones se asigna incorrectamente el `clustered index` a una columna identity sin mayor análisis cuando no se obtiene ningún beneficio de ello. Podría haber utilizado otro índice, pero la información para crear esa prueba es insuficiente. Por otro lado, no creo que el buen código sea optimización prematura. Al contrario, el mal código es deuda técnica y se puede esparcir como una plaga.

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez no entendí correctamente tu problema, pero si quieres las filas cuya fecha coincidan en día y hora con otra, ¿no es lo mismo que decir que la diferencia en horas entre ambas sea igual a 0?

```
SELECT *
      FROM X
      WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, FechaHora, @Now) = 0
```

Comment: Mi +1 por ser la solución más limpia y elegante. No la propuse porque pensé que la diferencia entre `2019-01-01 01:59:59` y `2019-01-01 02:00:00` (por poner un ejemplo) sería considerado `0` horas, pero tras probado he visto que no es el mismo comportamiento al que estoy acostumbrado en mysql (con `datediff` y `timediff`). La única pega que le veo es que no se puede optimizar la consulta con índices por forzar una operación sobre cada registro.

Comment: Totalmente @OscarGarcia, lo de `datediff` en `sqlserver`es un comportamiento "anti intuitivo", lo que ocurre es que las diferencias las mide igual que el `datepart` es decir por cada parte, en este caso las horas.

Answer (score 0):

Hacer la comparación de fechas utilizando cadenas de texto, teniendo tipos de datos nativos para manejo de fechas, no solo se siente *sucio* sino que es más ineficiente que realizar la comparación directa de fechas.

Si quieres comparar solamente la fecha, puedes *truncar* la parte de la hora forzando al motor a *convertir* a tipo `date` tus campos `datetime`.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
  FROM X
 WHERE cast(FechaHora as date) = cast(@Now as date)
   and datepart(hour, FechaHora) = datepart(hour, @Now);
```

O, quizás mejor todavía, declarar las variables desde el inicio, si es posible:

```
declare @Hoy date = getdate();
declare @Hora int = datepart(hour, getdate());

SELECT *
  FROM X
 WHERE cast(FechaHora as date) = @Hoy
   and datepart(hour, FechaHora) = @Hora;
```

Comment: Se pide comparar fecha y hora sin minutos. Esta solución solo abarca fecha y elimina las horas

Comment: Oh, gracias por el comentario, creo que leí demasiado rápido la pregunta.